# Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs

```js
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import axios from 'axios';
import videoDetails from './components/listvideos';

class YoutubeApp extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)

    this.state = {
          videos:[]
    };

    this.apiCall('surfing');
    
   
}
    apiCall(term){
        const params = {
            part: 'snippet',
            key:APP_KEY,
            q:term,
            type: 'video'
        };
    axios.get(APP_URL, { params: params})
        .then(function(response) {
           this.setState({
               videos:response
           })
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
        console.error(error);
      });
   }

    render(){
        
        return (
            <div>
            <videoDetails/>
            </div>
        )
    }


}


ReactDOM.render(
    <YoutubeApp/>,
    document.getElementById('app')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.8/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.8/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
</div>
```

Hi I am trying to make a youtube clone for practice I am a beginner on this but i cannot see why the state on react is giving me a problem
I am trying to set the state to my videos array so i can pass it to other components I didn't include the api key or url but is very readable by the way this is the error
{Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined}

Comment: binding issue use arrow function: `.then((response) =>  {`

Comment: Not a duplicate. Different things. The answer to this question is regarding ES6 not necessarily React.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using `function()` in your Promise chain, this will change the scope for `this`. If you're using ES6 I suggest you use the arrow function to maintain the class scope. Example:

You're using

```
axios.get(APP_URL, { params: params})
    .then(function(response) { // this resets the scope
       this.setState({
           videos:response
       })
    })
```

Try using arrow functions:

```
axios.get(APP_URL, { params: params})
    .then((response) => {
       this.setState({
           videos:response
       })
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the current context `this` to a variable, also be consistent either use ES5 or ES6.

```
apiCall(term) {
  const params = {
    part: 'snippet',
    key: APP_KEY,
    q: term,
    type: 'video'
  };
  const _this = this;

  axios.get(APP_URL, { params: params})
   .then((response) => {
     _this.setState({
       videos: response
     });
   })
   .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is due to scoping in your API call. The value of `this` is different within your `response` callback in your promise chain. There are two ways to solve this.

You could set a variable referencing `this` at the beginning of your `apiCall` method.

```
apiCall(term){

    const that = this;

    const params = {
        part: 'snippet',
        key:APP_KEY,
        q:term,
        type: 'video'
    };

   axios.get(APP_URL, { params: params}).then(function(response) {
       that.setState({
           videos:response
       });
    }).catch(function(error) {
       console.error(error);
  });
```

}

or else you can use ES6 arrow functions, which maintain the original scope, like this:

```
axios.get(APP_URL, { params: params}).then(response => {
    this.setState({
         videos:response
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You also may need to add `this.apiCall = this.apiCall.bind(this)` before the `this.apiCall('surfing');` on your `constructor` method. This will bind the scope of `apiCall` to the scope of the react component.

More here: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/handling-events.html

Also, remove `this.apiCall('surfing');` from the `constructor` and put it into a `componentDidMount` function, the constructor should not be used for execution.